# How to add selected record data in crystal report?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-2010

I have two tables and sample data is as follows.

```
  **Table 1**                      **Table 2**

 1 Reverse  50,000pcs              1 PVC 20
 2 New      10,000pcs              1 INK 30 
                                   2 MILKY 25 
                                   2 INK 35
```

when i select id=1 then i get records of id=1 from two tables as:

> ```
>  **Table 1**                               **Table 2**
> 1 Reverse  50,000pcs                        1 PVC 20     
>                                             1 INK 30
> ```

i just want to add last column of table's 2 as

```
1 PVC 20
1 INK 30
Total:50(i.e 20+30)
```

Comment: Search for `SUM()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Lw2aVYeBDouBqAbxjbKAAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=total+in+crystal+reports

Comment: it should also add for id=2 as 2,2 MILKY,INK    25+35=60